# Could not load type <User Control Name Here>

Tags: sharepoint-server, solution-deployment

I recently received a SharePoint Solution and a DB dump of a content database. I restored the content database and deployed the WSP file in my local and everything was working perfectly.

I tried deploying it to a different server by deploying the WSP file via PowerShell scripts. I didn't encounter any error during the deployment but upon loading the home page it throws me an error saying that the control type of a user control I created for the header can't be found.

I tried checking everything and it seems like everything is ok. Any ideas what else might be wrong?

Comment: could you post the screenshot of the issue? I believe the version of both the servers is same.

Comment: hi, the error is the generic error page  you get from SharePoint. And the error is "Could not load type MyNameSpace.ControlTemplates.UserControlName" then followed by the GUID of the error and the date and time.